# Could anyone explain this 置く置かない to me please

Tags: grammar, translation, verbs

I found the sentence

> けんかして嫁が出ていきました。
>   けんかの原因は、家に下宿人を**置く置かない**の件です

And I have a doubt about using of **置く置かない** How should it be translated ? and
How to use it 
I have never seen this grammar using before

Answer (score 5):

> 「Verb in Affirmative Form + Same Verb in Negative Form」

is a common expression meaning:

> "(a discussion of) the pros and cons of [Verb]-ing" or
>
> "whether or not one should [Verb]"

Thus, the passage:

> 「けんかして嫁{よめ}が出{で}ていきました。 けんかの原因{げんいん}は、家{いえ}に下宿人{げしゅくにん}を**置{お}く置{お}かない**の件{けん}です。」

means:

> "My wife left home after the fight.  The cause of our fight was regarding whether or not we should take in boarders/lodgers at our home."